# Angular 4 App - Allowing customers to link their bank accounts

Tags: android, ios, angular, stripe-payments, ionic3

I would like to know if there is a solution which allows me to create an app that allows users to sign in. They can then link their own bank account via Stripe (Stripe been integrated into the app).

The app will then accept payments and any payments made will go to their Stripe account.

I do not need the code for the whole app or the Stripe integration just some guidance on how this can be implemented.

I have had a look at the following Stripe resources - https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#bank-account-createToken

However I am not sure if there needs to be one main Stripe account (which I will create) and sub accounts underneath that (which the users will create) or if each user will have their own Stripe account (only accessible to them).

Also is there something special I need to implement when trying to configure automated payouts or is this handled by Stripe directly.

Is it also possible to charge a handling fee (for example 2%) from the payments made and if so is there any specific method the integration needs to happen or can it happen with a normal Stripe integration.

App is using the following,

Angular 4 
Ionic 3
Built for iOS and Android.

Comment: I do understand that this information might be available online, however I have not been able to track it down. If someone can provide me a link or example code which might direct me towards my final requirement that would be much appreciated.

Comment: edit tag to angular

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using [**Stripe Native plugin**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stripe/).Here is the [**Plugin's
repo**](https://github.com/zyra/cordova-plugin-stripe).

```
import { Stripe } from '@ionic-native/stripe';

constructor(private stripe: Stripe) { }

...

this.stripe.setPublishableKey('my_publishable_key');

let card = {
 number: '4242424242424242',
 expMonth: 12,
 expYear: 2020,
 cvc: '220'
};

this.stripe.createCardToken(card)
   .then(token => console.log(token))
   .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

For all your other business related questions you [**need to read this**](https://support.stripe.com/).If you unable to find a solution specific to you then you need to [**contact Stripe team**](https://support.stripe.com/email/login) for that.

If you need to see the real implementation then you can get the full source code of it [**from here (Commercial one (Just for $ 5))**](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201702241736843/stripe-with-ionic2-quickly-and-easily-integrate-stripe-in-your-ionic2-app#).This is their [**readme file**](https://github.com/sibizavic/stripe-with-ionic2-docs).But this implementation has not been used Cordova plugin which I have mentioned above.

Comment: By the looks of it I think that only accepts payments for one account. What I am after is to have people who register on the app to have their own Stripe account and accept payments to their account directly without having us (the app owners) worry about the funds.

Comment: Hope you can ask your use case from the Stripe team no? Hope they have customisation solutions too.

Comment: Hey I have contacted them as well, I was wondering if anyone had faces this before and how they went about it.. so hopefully Stripe will get back to me soon.

Comment: @Adrian Did you get a response regarding this from Stripe or do you have a reference to your question (like a feature request or something)? I am looking for exactly the same solution.

Comment: just found this meanwhile - https://stripe.com/connect - just sharing for someone who may end up here.

Comment: @Jothi yea thats the one I ended up using. It has the ability to do what I required.